# simple code metrics stand-alone maven plugin for java 7

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, code-analysis

I'm looking for a way to generate a simple metrics report (more specifically, lines of code) for a maven multi-module java 7 build.

- I've tried the maven [javancss plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javancss-maven-plugin/) but it chokes on java 7
  syntax and seems to be abandoned.
- I know about the maven [sonar plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/) but I dont want to install
  (and maintain) a sonar installation, I'd just like a simple static
  html.
- I've looked at [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) and [code analyzer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeanalyze-gpl/) but couldnt find any
  way of integrating them into a maven build

So my question is - how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonar is really easy to install. Download the package unzip it and run the batch script. It will use an embedded database and web server

Running Maven as follows assume Sonar is running locally, so you won't need any special configuration in your POM.

```
   mvn sonar:sonar
```

I suggest trying it out. It would seem to be more complex, but the Sonar team have done a lot of work to make Sonar really easy to use.

Comment: its not an ease-of-use issue. i just dont like the idea of the build not being "self contained" - you checkout, you build. i dont want any extra requirements beyond a jdk and maven

Comment: @radai All I can say is that in the past I never bothered enabling standard code analysis tooling (PMD, Checkstyle and Findbugs have been around for ages). Sonar has changed my mind, there is now no excuse for performing a lot more analysis than just simple lines of code metrics. You must try it out, it will make you a better programmer

Comment: as the question implies, im all for code analysis. im just looking for something more along the lines of the unix mentality of small focused tools.

Comment: If you have docker installed, you can run sonar in docker: https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/

Comment: @MartijnBurger Very true, I'm a big docker fan. Mind you, Docker wasn't an option when this question was originally asked :-)